# Accept multiple enums as a single argument with swift

Tags: swift, enums

I have a couple of methods that take an array of enums as an argument, however I see that for example when changing a time interval into components, I call

```
    func components(_ unitFlags: NSCalendar.Unit, from startingDate: Date, to resultDate: Date, options opts: NSCalendar.Options = []) -> DateComponents
```

where `unitFlags` accepts multiple values. For example, I can pass `[.year, .month]` even though the function parameter is not defined as an array of NSCalendar units. How can I achieve this behaviour in my custom enums/functions?

Thanks

Comment: `NSCalendar.Unit` is [OptionSet](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset), not enum and you are mixing up Swift 2 and 3 syntax. In Swift 3 it's `Calendar.Component` the entire method is `func dateComponents(_ components: Set<Calendar.Component>, from start: Date, to end: Date) -> DateComponents`

Comment: Thanks vadian, I will have to take a look at OptionSet, I never heard of such a thing before. (And my example is Swift 4)

Comment: The signature of the method in Swift 3 and 4 is the same and I'm talking about native `Calendar` struct rather than `NSCalendar`. Do not use `NSCalendar` in Swift 3+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example, I can pass `[.year, .month]`

That is not an array of enums. It is a [Option Set](http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECoptionsSets). In effect, what's expected here is a Set of struct static properties.

That's a nice bit of syntax but it likely wouldn't be appropriate for your use case, as you really do probably want an array of enum. Option Sets are a way of constructing and manipulating bitmasks, which is not what you have.